# Change color palette in e_visual_map from echart4r

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, echarts

Is it possible to change the colour palette using the function `e_visual_map` from the package `echart4r`.

The default is the following.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(echarts4r)
data(mtcars)

mtcars |>
  e_charts(mpg) |>
  e_scatter(wt, qsec, scale = e_scale) |>
  e_visual_map(qsec, scale = e_scale)
```

[image]
For example, is it possible to use the Viridis colour palette from the package ggplot2?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `color` as an additional argument, then you can input `viridis` as the parameter. Or you can put in a list of colors (e.g., `color = c("#8DD3C7", "#FFFFB3", "#BEBADA", "#FB8072")`).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(echarts4r)
library(viridis)

mtcars |>
    e_charts(mpg) |>
    e_scatter(wt, qsec, scale = e_scale) |>
    e_visual_map(qsec, scale = e_scale, color = viridis(5))
```

[image]